# how to define pseudo element :: after the same width as its parent

Tags: html, css

```
.list li::after{
    content:" ";
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: green;
}
ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 2.5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i get over mouse `li` tag, I want to have liner after it, but this liner should be the same width as his `li`. Also I don't know how to active `::after`, after `:hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple gradient:

```css
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 2.5px;
  
  background-image:linear-gradient(green,green);
  background-size:0% 2px;
  background-position:bottom left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:1s all;
}
a:hover {
  background-size:100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as i want, but is it hard to do  with ::after ?

Comment: @Hydsoled no it's not hard but this is easier .. here is with pseudo element: https://jsfiddle.net/c1hybedx/

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to make use of [`border-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom) on the `<a>` element. You can control how far away this underline is from the text with [`padding-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom).

This avoids the need for `::after` completely, and can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  /*padding: 10px 20px;*/
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 2.5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the width of the line (the border) is controlled by the amount of horizontal `padding` on the element. I've commented this padding out in the above example to show the line at the exact same width as the link.

Comment: i thought that but, when i get over mouse on it, that wouldn't have animation, like that: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition4)